# Accessing Row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following ASPX code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="BRANCH_NAME" runat="server" 
          NavigateUrl='<%# "mailto:"+Eval("OWNERS_EMAIL") %>' 
          Text='<%# Eval("BRANCH_NAME") %>' 
          ToolTip='<%# GetBranchAddress() %> '> 
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The function in the code behind:

```
protected string GetBranchAddress(DataRow row)
{
    return "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">"+ 
               row["BRANCH_NAME"].ToString().Trim() + "</span><br />" + 
               row["OWNERS_FIRST_NAME"].ToString().Trim() + " " +
               row["OWNERS_LAST_NAME"].ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
               row["OWNERS_EMAIL"].ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
               row["OWNERS_OFFICE_PHONE"].ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
               row["OWNERS_FAX_PHONE"].ToString().Trim();

}
```

The error I get is:

> No overload for method 'GetBranchAddress' takes '0' arguments

How can I access `row` in my ASP GridView so that I can pass it to my function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to pass the entire `DataRow` into the function, utilize datakeys to specify the fields you want to display, and pass in the row index.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="BRANCH_NAME, StreetAddress" ...>
```

The code in the `ItemTemplate` would look something like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="BRANCH_NAME" runat="server" 
          NavigateUrl='<%# "mailto:"+Eval("OWNERS_EMAIL") %>' 
          Text='<%# Eval("BRANCH_NAME") %>' 
          ToolTip='<%# GetBranchAddress(Container.DisplayIndex) %> '> 
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In your function, you can access the datakey values like this:

```
protected string GetBranchAddress(int rowIndex)
{
    return GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex]["BRANCH_NAME"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but if I'm specifying column names, I may as well just pass them directly into my function like `GetBranchAddress(Eval("BRANCH_NAME"), Eval("BRANCH_EMAIL"))`.

Comment: One way or another you'll have to specify column names somewhere, and it would be easier to make maintain if they were specified in the markup vs. code-behind. Is there a specific reason why you're approaching it this way?

Comment: I just like to make things more "MVC" by keeping as much business logic as possible outside of the view.

Comment: You can always specify datakeys in code-behind if you prefer, which will allow you to keep it outside of the view.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, you're not passing any parameters in to GetBranchAddress, which is why you're getting the error.  You should pass "this" into the method, where "this" is the currently operated on object (the DataRow).  For example,

```
ToolTip='<%# GetBranchAddress(this) %> '
```

Comment: I tried passing `this` but it gives me another error `The best overloaded method match for 'SplendidCRM.WebForms.client_home2.GetBranchAddress(System.Data.DataRow)' has some invalid arguments`